# What is meant by in Google play developer console that All statistics are calculated based on the PST/PDT timezone.?

Tags: developer-console

I want to know my current installs/Total installs at current time but some days of week my app installs are update daily basis and some days my app installs are not update daily basis like I observed Friday, Saturday Sunday and Monday my app install updates on daily basis and on other days my installs do not update on daily basis. And below there is small line written on a developer console that All statistics are calculated based on the PST/PDT timezone. Can anyone guide me what does that line mean and how this line relates to installs updating in Google Play Developer Console.....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Er its just the timezone California happens to be in: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/pdt

Comment: Thanks but can you relate this with app installs showing in google play developer console. And how in normal routine it shows to the developer

Comment: It means that if you see a date or time its the date and time in (say) California so you would need to adjust it for your timezone to get your local time.